# Singly linked list, A small problem in main function

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

Wrote this program to delete Node with same  data in a sorted linked list, but the `while` loop is not executing as expected . By using some `printf` statements, I figured out while loop was executed once ,but statements after first if condition is not executed.
Can you please reply me why this is happening ,and how can I solve this?

*Note* : `Insert` and `Print` function are user defined functions.

`Insert(&Head,char data)`: it inserts data at the begining of linked list every time it is called;

```
void Insert(struct Node **Head, char data)
{
    struct Node *temp = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = *Head;
    *Head = temp;
}
```

`Print` :it takes head of List and prints the linked list in output terminal.

```
void Print(struct Node *Head)
{
    printf("%c", Head->data);
    while (Head->next != NULL)
    {
        Head = Head->next;
        printf("\t%c", Head->data);
    } 
}
```

...

```
int main()
{
    struct Node *Head = NULL;
    Insert(&Head, '6');
    Insert(&Head, '5');
    Insert(&Head, '5');
    Insert(&Head, '5');
    Insert(&Head, '5');
    Insert(&Head, '5');
    Insert(&Head, '5');
    Insert(&Head, '4');
    Insert(&Head, '4');
    Insert(&Head, '3');
    Insert(&Head, '2');
    Insert(&Head, '1');
    Insert(&Head, '1');
    Insert(&Head, '1');

    printf("dta---%c\n", Head->data);
    Print(Head);

    //Code to deleate duplicate data  from a sorted singly linked list
    struct Node *PreviousHead = NULL;
    while (Head != NULL)
    {
        if (PreviousHead->data == Head->data) //i think there is some error in this statement...
        {
            while (PreviousHead->data == Head->data)
            {
                
                PreviousHead->next = Head->next;
                free(Head);
                Head = PreviousHead->next;
                if (Head == NULL)
                    break;
            }
        }
        
        PreviousHead = Head;
        Head = Head->next;

        if (PreviousHead->data == Head->data)
        {
            PreviousHead->next = Head->next;
            free(Head);
            Head = PreviousHead->next;
        }
    }
    Print(Head);
}
```

Comment: "Note : Insert and Print function are user defined functions" -- which doesn't really tell us what they are. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: thank you for asking ,i have edited my question and added some more details,I hope it will help.

Comment: Describing what the functions do (in prose) is not part of a reproducible example... you need to include code.

Comment: But that being said, I do see one immediate problem with your code: you initialize `PreviousHead` to `NULL`, and then 3-lines later reference `PreviousHead->data`, and accessing a structure element from a `NULL` pointer is undefined behavior. You need to consider what is is you really want to do there.

Comment: @SGeorgiades In this program i wanted to delete repeated data, for doing so I created a variable `PrevioousHead` to keep track of previous node of list , i created a `while` loop to loop till the end of linked list , Inside loop i  wrote to compare data in current node(Head) with the data in previous node, if data is Not Equal ,PreviousHead and head Node Moves one Node forwards,if data is same,  the data is deleated  and move head forward untill end is not reached.

Comment: @SGeorgiades How Should i create PreviousNode so that it will work,?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for deleting duplicates from a singly linked list. You have a lot of issues with NULL checking and unnecessary code.

```
while (Head != NULL)
{
    struct Node *next = Head->next;

    while (next != NULL && Head->data == next->data) {
        Head->next = next->next;
        free(next)
        next = Head->next;
    }

    Head = Head->next;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters you does not have a sorted linked list. That is in general the user  can enter values in any order into list.

If you want to have a sorted linked list you need to change the function `Insert`,

Also allocation of memory for a node can fail. You should process such a situation within the function.

The function can look the following way.

```
int Insert( struct Node **head, char data )
{
    struct Node *temp = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
    int success = temp != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        temp->data = data;
        
        while ( *head && !( data < ( *head )->data ) ) head = &( *head )->next;
        
        temp->next = *head;
        *head = temp;
    }
    
    return success;
}
```

The function `Print` can invoke undefined behavior if the user of the function will pass a null pointer (an empty list) because there is no check in the function whether the passed pointer is equal to `NULL`. So this statement

```
void Print(struct Node *Head)
{
    printf("%c", Head->data);
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

invokes undefined behavior.

In `main` where you are trying to delete duplicates the while loop in turn invokes undefined behavior because initially the pointer `PreviousHead` is set to `NULL` and this null pointer is used to access memory

```
struct Node *PreviousHead = NULL;
while (Head != NULL)
{
    if (PreviousHead->data == Head->data)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You should write a separate function the same way as you wrote for example the function that inserts nodes into the list.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how described functions can be written.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct Node
{
    char data;
    struct Node *next;
}; 

int Insert( struct Node **head, char data )
{
    struct Node *temp = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
    int success = temp != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        temp->data = data;
        
        while ( *head && !( data < ( *head )->data ) ) head = &( *head )->next;
        
        temp->next = *head;
        *head = temp;
    }
    
    return success;
}

FILE * Print( const struct Node *head, FILE *fp )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        fprintf( fp, "%c\t", head->data );
    }
    
    fputs( "null", fp );
    
    return fp;
}


void RemoveDuplicates( struct Node **head )
{
    struct Node *current = *head;
    
    while ( current && current->next )
    {
        if ( current->data == current->next->data )
        {
            struct Node *temp = current->next;
            current->next = current->next->next;
            free( temp );
        }
        else
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
}

void clear( struct Node **head )
{
    while ( *head )
    {
        struct Node *temp = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;
        free( temp );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct Node *head = NULL;
    
    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );
    
    const int N = 10;
    
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        Insert( &head, '0' + rand() % N );
    }
    
    fputc( '\n', Print( head, stdout ) );
    
    RemoveDuplicates( &head );

    fputc( '\n', Print( head, stdout ) );

    clear( &head );
    
    fputc( '\n', Print( head, stdout ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
0   0   1   1   2   2   3   4   7   7   null
0   1   2   3   4   7   null
null
```